# SOLR - old Transactions-Logs (tlogs) never deleted

Tags: solr, indexing, transaction-log

first of all to mention i searched a long time but got n solution, so not i try with my specific problem, trying to keep it short:

- solr-spec 4.0.0.2012.10.06.03.04.33
- one master, three slaves
- around 70.000 documents in index
- master gets triggered to full import / generate complete new index ~ once a day
- command line options for trigger are: 
  ?command=full-import&verbose=false&clean=false&commit=true&optimize=true
- slaves trigger master for new index, if GEN increases (full import + hard commit as mentioned), they pull the new index
- no autoCommit / autoSoftCommit set up

the problem ist, that each hard commit the index (~670MB) gets written to disk, once a day, but the old never get deleted.
As far as i read solr keeps enough tlogs to be able to restore the last 100 changes to documents, am i right?

In my setup i am sure at least 100 documents (or data sets within the source database) are changed each day, so i dont understand why solr never deletes old tlogs.

I would be glad if someone can point to the right direction, currently i have no clue what to try next. Also i did not find a setup like this one described having problems like this.

Thx ;)

Answer (score 1):

First you'll probably want to update your Solr-version, as there's been a few transaction log reference leaks fixed since 4.0.

A hard commit should usually remove old transaction logs as the documents are written to disk in the index anyway iirc, which may indicate that you're getting bit by some old references hanging around.

Another option would be to turn off the transaction log completely, since you only generate a completely new index each run anyway and dist that one.

Comment: Hi, thx for the quick reply, yes i already thought about upgrading the version, maybe i start with this and check if tlogs are rotaded as expected.  You even suggest turning off hard commits? Well, as i understand for me it only works as a "backup" in case of crash for the master, right? But as long i only do hard commits and only replicate the full index to the slaves i dont need a tlog to keep the slaves synced, right?

Comment: Right, turning off tlogs, not hard commits. The tlog wouldn't be of much use anyway, since you're hard committing and  replicating the complete, new index anyway.

Comment: I heard from a colleague that the tlogs could be important for restore in case for example my master hangs and i need to kill the process, resulting in corrupt main index. What about that? Myself i´m quite skeptical and don´t think the tlogs can help in this case anyway, what you think?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you won't get a corrupt index (at least that's never happened to us), and if it's corrupt, the transaction log won't be able to save you anyway (what should it update?). The transaction log is mainly used for near realtime search, distributing operations in SolrCloud etc. You'd probably be better off just kicking off a new index if your master index gets corrupted for some other reason. The transaction log count is also related to the number of commits, not the number of documents updates iirc.

Comment: if its the number of commits ... i could activate AutoSoftCommit each few minutes, right? Even without actual changes to the data this would "count" as a commit as far as related to this "100", right?

Comment: I'd guess so. Try it and see. A hard commit should always clear the transaction log as far as I know, however.